# How can I get allowedConferenceSolutionTypes "eventHangout" in the Calendar creation response?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, odoo, google-hangouts

When I insert calendar with allowedConferenceSolutionTypes "eventHangout" using Calendar API but a response is provided "hangoutsMeet" but as per Google Calendar API response should be provided "eventHangout".

Request for creating calendar:

POST [https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]](https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars?key=%5BYOUR_API_KEY%5D) HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
"summary": "Event Hangout",
"conferenceProperties": {
"allowedConferenceSolutionTypes": [
"eventHangout"
]
}
}

Response:
{
"kind": "calendar#calendar",
"etag": ""ZK9fcme_JbF_CB4WYnKnXWUeuYw"",
"id": "1n9qoe2np18slfqoq1sjd0lh3o@group.calendar.google.com",
"summary": "Event Hangout",
"timeZone": "UTC",
"conferenceProperties": {
"allowedConferenceSolutionTypes": [
"hangoutsMeet"
]
}
}

How can I get allowedConferenceSolutionTypes "eventHangout" in the Calendar creation response?

it's always return "allowedConferenceSolutionTypes":["hangoutsMeet"]

Not eventHangout

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set/modify the calendar's `allowedConferenceSolutionTypes` property.

When creating a new calendar using [Calendars.insert()](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert?hl=en) you need to supply a [Calendar resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars#resource) in the request body having the `summary` as a required property

If you will check other properties available for the [Calendar resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars#resource), `conferenceProperties` is not a writable property. Hence you cannot modify that property.

> See notes column to identify writable properties.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response.

How can I create a calendar with allowedConferenceSolutionTypes: ["hangoutsMeet", "eventHangout"].

Comment: Sorry it is not possible anymore. Hangouts is migrating to Google Chats/Meet, see the following references: [The latest on Google Hangouts and the upgrade to Google Chat](https://blog.google/products/workspace/latest-google-hangouts-and-upgrade-google-chat/),  [What is the difference between Google Hangouts, Hangouts Meet, and Google Meet?](https://apps.google.com/intl/en/meet/#:~:text=Hangouts%20Meet%20and%20Hangouts%20Chat,new%20Meet%20and%20Chat%20products)